# Suspend JavaScript keydown event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Is it possible to suspend `keydown` (and following `keypress`, `keyup`) event in JavaScript?

The case is:

> Press some button (for example, "Enter" key), sleep for 5 seconds and
> continue this event

Comment: What do you mean by "continue this event"?

Comment: What are you really trying to do

Comment: I want that event will happen only after some timeout (5 secs, etc.)

Comment: What if "Enter" has been pressed a few times during this interval. Do you want all of these events to "occur" later? What are you actually trying to achieve with this?

Comment: You can't suspend an event as such. I'd need more specifics to provide an example but you could for example capture an event, defer for 5 seconds and trigger it again. Or I'm guessing more likely you just want to defer the method that the event calls yes?

Comment: "What if "Enter"has been pressed"
Lets start from simple case, no such events yet

Answer (score 1):

The below pure JS solution will prevent multiple events from firing if the timer is running.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bYnYw/).

```
document.onkeydown = (function() {
    var isActive = false;

    return function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13 && !isActive) {
            isActive = true;
            setTimeout(function() {
                isActive = false;

                // Your code here...

            }, 5000);
        }
    };

})();
```